# How can I write a schedule for this batch inside the same class

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, schedulebatch

```
    global class NumberOfContactsBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select Id from Account order by Name]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Account> scope) {
        List<Account> accountUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for (AggregateResult ar : [
                select AccountId a, count(Id) c
                from Contact
                where AccountId in :scope
                group by AccountId
                ]) {
            accountUpdate.add(new Account(
                    Id = (Id) ar.get('a'),
                    Number_of_Contacts__c = (Decimal) ar.get('c')
                    ));
        }
        update accountUpdate;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    }
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC){
        database.executeBatch(new NumberOfContactsBatch());
        String cronExpression = '';
        System.schedule(cronExpression);        
    } 
}
```

I got stuck here where I want write a scheduler which runs every six hours

Comment: Your scheduler is already written correctly. Do not put any cron in your class. Use an anonymous script for that.

Comment: Actually it is giving me this error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void schedule(String) from the type System" 
I mean after this i only have to execute it like this Database.executeBatch(new NumberOfContactsBatch());
isnt it?

Comment: Remove everything from your scheduler except `Database.executeBatch`

Comment: ok got it. Then I have to write this line NumberOfContactsBatch obj = new  NumberOfContactsBatch();
String cron = 'my cron expression';
String jobId = System.schedule('Job', cron, obj); 

Thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to Schedule a batch class without a scheduler to Implement SchedulableContext, for this [Schedulable Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) should be implemented

**For Example**:

```
Class NumberOfContactsSchedulabler implements Schedulable {
     global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) { 
        database.executeBatch(new NumberOfContactsBatch());
    }
}
```

Run the following Code in [anonymous window](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_execute_anonymous.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) (One time)

```
NumberOfContactsSchedulabler m = new NumberOfContactsSchedulabler();
String sch = '0 0 0/6 1/1 * ? *'; //Schedules the job to run every 6 hours
String jobID = system.schedule('Contacts Schedulable', sch, m);
```

Cron maker help can be found [here](http://www.cronmaker.com/?1)

Also the Method "global void execute(SchedulableContext SC)" can be removed